# Data base login error when connecting from webmatrix

Tags: joomla2.5, webmatrix

I have installed joomla 2.5 template in webmatrix with mysql as database.Enterd the pasword and confirmed as well. After installing the template in webmatrix there is an option to configure database connection. I am trying for the new data base connection which is microsoft sql 2008 express. Trying to connect with windows authentication its not connecting. the error is

"Cannot open database xyz"

My database name is present.

Please confirm me
1) Can we connect to sql express or do we require standalone application?
2) In my pc localmachine mysql is not installed then at the time of installation why is it asking mysql password?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer,

The coonection string was wrong. Corrected the connection string .